# Different border images on a div

Tags: css, border, border-image

I am trying to use 2 different border images on the same div: one image repeated along the top, one along the bottom.

I can get the bottom border image to display. I can also get the same border image repeat along the top, but once I try to use border-bottom-image or border-top-image, neither displays:

```css
#mainImage{
    border-bottom:8px solid #fff;
    border-bottom-image: url("http://local.vsjf.org/wp-content/themes/vsjf/images/vsjf_borders_sage_02.png") 7 repeat;
    border-top:8px solid transparent;
    border-top-image: url("http://local.vsjf.org/wp-content/themes/vsjf/images/vsjf_borders_white.png") 7 repeat;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've never came upon using border-images, I suppose there are some tags that are rarely used for CSS.

I think a great option which would likely produce the result you're wanting is to use :before and :after styles which can be even more flexible than border-image, because you can define :before and :after almost as separate elements, but they are a part of the element which makes it relative by default.

```
#mainImage:before {background-image: url('/*url*/'); width: #px; height: #px; position: /*relative*/; content:''; }
#mainImage:after {background-image: url('/*url*/'); width: #px; height: #px; position: /*relative*/; content:'';}
```